# Resampling a dataset of x rows

Tags: r

I have a data set of x entries, and I need to resample it to y entries, with y being a number smaller than x. my data set is not a series of numbers, of rather x rows, and I need the entire row of information when resampling.

I am aware of the sample() function but given that my dataset is not a vector I am unclear how the exact code should be written.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try taking of a sample of the object's `row.names` or a sample from `1:nrow(object)`.

Comment: ^ to make this more explicit: `my_data_frame[sample(nrow(my_data_frame), 10), ]` gives 10 random rows from `my_data_frame`

Comment: questions run a lot smoother when you provide sample data to copy and paste for reviewers. Feel free to edit with some sample data to play with. Welcome to SO

Comment: If you want to randomly pull out a subset, you just need to `sample()` the vector of row indices `nrow(df)` then use the indices to get your new dataframe.

Comment: do you want to sample with or w/o replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that you want to sample the index of rows, then use that to pull back all of the columns for those rows, like so:

```
set.seed(4444)  # for reproducibility
data(iris)

x <- nrow(iris)
y <- 7

irisSubset <- iris[sample(x,y),]
```

Comment: note that this is sampling without replacement.  If you are doing bootstrap resampling you should do `replace=TRUE`